# How to resize an R code output on Beamer Latex

Tags: latex, knitr, beamer

I would like to resize my R code output on Beamer Latex. I have something like :

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Application du modèle : contenu de lung}

<<echo=FALSE>>=
library(survival)
attach(lung)
head(lung)
@

\textbf{\underline{Objectif:}} construire un modèle qui vérifie les hypothèses de Cox 
à partir de ce jeu de données
\end{frame}
```

The problem is that the output table protrudes from the slide.
Thanks.

Edit : also when i try to compile this part of code

```
\begin{frame}{Premier modèle naïf}
<<echo=FALSE, linebreaks=TRUE>>=
library(survival)
model_1<-coxph(Surv(time,status) ~ age+factor(sex)+ph.ecog+wt.loss, data = lung)
cox.zph(model_1)
@
\textbf{\underline{Objectif:}} construire un modèle qui vérifie les hypothèses de Cox à partir de ce jeu de données
\end{frame}
```

It looks like :

[image: Problem]

Comment: Can you add the intermediate .tex file?

Comment: You mean you want the whole file ?

Comment: If possible? Alternatively please add instructions how you compile this.

Comment: I compile this code on Overleaf

Comment: Your second example lacks the fragile option. If I add it, it looks nice https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7lmX.png

Comment: Just for information, is it possible to increase the size a little ?

Comment: Replace `\tiny` with whatever font size you like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally this kniter thingy seems wrap the code in a custom environment called `kframe`. You can change the font size for this environment like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginEnvironment{kframe}{\tiny}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Application du modèle : contenu de lung}

<<echo=FALSE>>=
library(survival)
attach(lung)
head(lung)
@

\textbf{\underline{Objectif:}} construire un modèle qui vérifie les hypothèses de Cox 
à partir de ce jeu de données
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Okay it works for `head(lung)` but if i try to compile this code `library(survival)
    model_1<-coxph(Surv(time,status) ~ age+factor(sex)+ph.ecog+wt.loss, data = lung)
    cox.zph(model_1)` it looks like very bad

Comment: @Matt99 Please make a compilable [mre] or show the intermediate .tex file

Comment: I made an edition.